# Finding a specific command without an empty line before it

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

I need to leave an empty line before all the "returns" in a visual studio 2013 project:
So I am using the find and replace.
I know the following regex expressions finds all the empty lines

```
^\s+$\n
```

how can I find all the returns that do not have an empty line before them?

For example this should be found in the search result:

```
Some Codes;
return (someObject);
}
```

Not this one:

```
SomeCodes;

return(someObject);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find a `return` that has *no* blank line before it, you must find lines that contains `return` (most likely with some amount of whitespace before it!), and then check with a Negative Lookbehind if the characters before it are *not* 2 hard returns. It must be **two** hard returns, because the first one will always be there -- it's the one that put the `return` on a line of its own. The second hard return is the one you need for a blank line. Since it is a *negative* lookbehind, it will match lines that do not match.

#### Wrong (should be found):

`... code .. \n
    return;`

#### Correct:

`... code .. \n
\n
    return;`

This ought to work, providing the regex parser supports Negative Lookbehinds:

```
(?<!\n)(?<![\t ])[\t ]*\n[\t ]*return
```

The extra lookbehind `(?<![\t ])` is because otherwise GREP will happily ignore `\n (space) \n`, as it has "zero times space **and** not a return before that". GREP is very literal minded.

---

If your editor does not support Negative Lookbehind, you can use a simpler variant:

```
[^\n][\t ]*\n[\t ]*return
```

This will report a false match on otherwise empty lines that contain whitespace (tab or spaces), so you may want to remove that beforehand by replacing

```
[\t ]+$
```

with nothing.

Comment: Thanks! but this still does not find anything!

Comment: @Maryam: I think you need to investigate if your IDE supports Negative Lookbehind then. It works as advertised in the code editor I use.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 and .Net Framework 4.5. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx   it should support the Negative Lookbehind. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @Maryam: the editor I tested with requires `\r` for newlines, not `\n`, and I was sure I replaced all of them before posting -- but it seems I still forgot to change one. If it still fails, try the simpler variant.

Comment: Thanks Jongware!   [^\n][\t ]*\n[\t ]*return   and   (?<!\n)(?<![\t ])[\t ]*\n[\t ]*return   find both cases. I am looking for the ones that do not have an empty line before them. but this one works : [^\r?\n][\t ]*\r?\n[\t ]*return

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. As I found the answer with your help please provide   [^\r?\n][\t ]*\r?\n[\t ]*return    as a separate answer so I select it.

Comment: @Maryam: thank you for trying along, but there is an error in your suggested expression. The part `[^\r?\n]` checks for *one of* the characters, so in this case it looks for **either** an `\r`, `\n`, or `?`!

Comment: I found the new line expression here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx
Please search for \r?\n on the page.